Load Videos in Batches of 20 in Android Java
I want to load my video by Batches of 20, so that my app will not lag. My app loads all videos at same time, which causes it to lag or sometimes crash.
public class AllVideosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityAllVideosBinding binding;
    ArrayList<VideoItem> videoList;
    ListVideoAdapter adapter;

    String foldername;
    String folderPath;

    private static String AD_UNIT_BANNER = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/9214589741";
    public static InterstitialAd interaddds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityAllVideosBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.foldertitle.setSelected(true);
        folderPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("folderPath");
        videoList = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayUtil.videoItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayUtil.videoItemArrayList.addAll(videoList);
        adapter = new ListVideoAdapter(videoList, this, 1, new OnClickAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AllVideosActivity.this, VideoPlaingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                intent.putExtra("videotitle", videoList.get(position).getVideoName());
                intent.putExtra("videopath", videoList.get(position).getVideoPath());
                intent.putExtra("foldername", foldername);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        listVideos();

        binding.videolist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        binding.videolist.setAdapter(adapter);

        foldername = getIntent().getStringExtra("folderName");

        binding.foldertitle.setText(foldername);    


        binding.back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            onBackPressed();
        });


    }

    private void listVideos() {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
        };

        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + folderPath + "%"};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC";


        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String videoName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
                String videoPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                String videoDuration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
                long videoSize = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
                long modifiedDateMillis = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)) * 1000L;


                String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd MMM", Locale.getDefault()).format(modifiedDateMillis);


                VideoItem videoItem = new VideoItem(videoName, videoPath, videoDuration, videoSize, formattedDate, null);
                videoList.add(videoItem);
                ArrayUtil.videoItemArrayList.add(videoItem);


            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

 

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = newBase.getSharedPreferences("LanguagePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String keylott = sharedPreferences.getString("keylot", "en");
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.setLocale(newBase, keylott));
    }
}

In this code I'm fetching videos from my phone and showing them in my app. I want to load only 20 videos first and then if user scrolls down, the next 20 video should be loaded automatically. However, in my call all the videos are loaded at the same time.
How can I load only 20 videos at a time?
